# Unir duas consultas SQL MariaDB

Tags: sql, join, group-by, mariadb, inner

Duas tabelas `tab_Ord_Ser` e `tab_Pos_Alb`.
Em duas consultas diferentes eu consigo saber os valores mas não estou conseguindo uni-las em apenas uma.
São elas:

```
SELECT
    Prazo_Producao as Data, 
    COUNT( `Numero OS` ) AS Produzir,
    Tipo_Album 
FROM
    tab_Ord_Ser 
WHERE
    Prazo_Producao >= "2018-03-01" 
GROUP BY
    Prazo_Producao,
    Tipo_Album
```

e

```
SELECT
    tab_Pos_Alb.`Data`,
    COUNT( tab_Pos_Alb.`Numero OS` ) AS Produzido,
    tab_Ord_Ser.Tipo_Album 
FROM
    tab_Ord_Ser
    INNER JOIN tab_Pos_Alb ON tab_Ord_Ser.`Numero OS` = tab_Pos_Alb.`Numero OS` 
WHERE
    ( tab_Pos_Alb.STATUS = "15 - Limpeza Saída" OR tab_Pos_Alb.STATUS = "46 - Finalizado" ) 
    AND tab_Pos_Alb.`Data` >= "2018-03-01" 
GROUP BY
    tab_Pos_Alb.`Data`,
    tab_Ord_Ser.Tipo_Album
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: o que já tentou?

Comment: já tentei usar subconsultas mas vai um pouco além do meu conhecimento, apesar te ter pesquisado bastante não consegui construir a consulta

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o **UNION ALL**:

```
SELECT
    Prazo_Producao as Data, 
    COUNT( `Numero OS` ) AS Produzir,
    Tipo_Album 
FROM
    tab_Ord_Ser 
WHERE
    Prazo_Producao >= "2018-03-01" 
GROUP BY
Prazo_Producao,
Tipo_Album

UNION ALL

SELECT
    tab_Pos_Alb.`Data`,
    COUNT( tab_Pos_Alb.`Numero OS` ) AS Produzido,
    tab_Ord_Ser.Tipo_Album 
FROM
    tab_Ord_Ser
    INNER JOIN tab_Pos_Alb ON tab_Ord_Ser.`Numero OS` = tab_Pos_Alb.`Numero OS` 
WHERE
    ( tab_Pos_Alb.STATUS = "15 - Limpeza Saída" OR tab_Pos_Alb.STATUS = "46 - Finalizado" ) 
    AND tab_Pos_Alb.`Data` >= "2018-03-01" 
GROUP BY
tab_Pos_Alb.`Data`,
tab_Ord_Ser.Tipo_Album
```

Porém nunca se esqueça que o **UNION ALL** exige que a quantidade das colunas de ambas as tabelas sejam as mesmas.

Comment: infelizmente a quantidade de colunas não são as mesmas

Comment: @MárcioJoséRosa mesmo que você realize uma consulta em tabelas com estruturas distintas (supondo que um possuí três colunas e a outra cinco colunas por exemplo), o seu `select` deve trazer a mesma quantidade de colunas para o **UNION ALL** funcionar: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab1 UNION ALL SELECT col3, col4 FROM tab2`. Perceba que são tabelas distintas porém a consulta seleciona a mesma quantidade de colunas entre tais tabelas.

Comment: Uma breve explicação [aqui](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php)

Comment: devo estar errando algo pois o resultado não é o esperado